# Magento 2 : Impossible to retreive the customer id of the session in an external script

Tags: session, magento2, indexer

I created an external script `test.php` inside Magento 2 at the root. But, I don't succeed to retrieve the customer ID of the session in this external script.

The script is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/bootstrap.php';

$params = array(
    Mage::PARAM_RUN_CODE => '',
    Mage::PARAM_RUN_TYPE => 'store',
    'entryPoint' => basename(__FILE__)  ,          
);

$entryPoint = new Mage_Index_Model_EntryPoint_Indexer(BP, $params);
$entryPoint->processRequest();       

$customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Customer_Model_Session')->getCustomerId();

echo "  customer_id session :  ".$customer_id;
```

To test, firstly, I authenticate a customer via Magento. Secondly, I launch the script `test.php`. But the customer ID session isn't displayed.

Could anyone explain how to retrieve session customer data in an external script?

Comment: Forget what I wrote, I have no idea yet of magento 2

Comment: I thought Magento 2 questions are not (yet) allowed here. http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79/are-magento-2-0-questions-allowed If they are allowed now please tell me. I got a few.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that you are running in an external script, it is rather that you are loading up the `Mage_Index_Model_EntryPoint_Indexer` which does not initialize for handling an HTTP request as `Mage_Core_Model_EntryPoint_Http` does. The indexer entry point is intended merely as a means of running the indexes, it's the entry point for the shell script `dev/scripts/indexer.php` and not intended to interface with the HTTP protocol.

Granted you need to get a customer id for the currently logged in customer, I would suggest using a different (more appropriate) entry point for your script.

Comment: I replaced Mage_Index_Model_EntryPoint_Indexer by Mage_Core_Model_EntryPoint_Http . The session id is  displayed at the foot of the page.Whent i launch this script, the magento application is launched like index.php wit the customer id session displayed at the botton of the home page. I just  want to launch an external script retreiving the custommer id session without to launch Magento

Do you have an idea how to do it ?.

Comment: you suggest me  using a different (more appropriate) entry point for the external script to retreive the customer Id session  without to launch Magento.  Can you explain what is the good entry point. Indeed; Magento has 3 class entry point Cron, Http, and Media. I tried the 3 but . Onnly , Mage_Core_Model_EntryPoint_Http reteived me the customer Id. But, Magento is launched at home .So, can you explain  me what entry Point to use and how to use it ?. If it doesnt exist, can you please test and give me a script that permits to retreive the customer Id Session without to launch magento.Thanks

Comment: If you only want the output of the session cookie, you will either have to write your own entry point (not recommended) or add a controller/action with an empty layout, but which prints out the session info. I.e. it will take more work than being a single-file script to pull the info.

Answer (score 1):

Just double make sure you have the latest copy of Magento 2 from github.

Just try this it might work.

```
$entryPoint = new Mage_Core_Model_EntryPoint_Http(new Mage_Core_Model_Config_Primary(BP, $_SERVER));
$entryPoint->processRequest();
$customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Customer_Model_Session')->getCustomerId();

echo "  customer_id session :  ".$customer_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced Mage_Index_Model_EntryPoint_Indexer by Mage_Core_Model_EntryPoint_Http . The session id is  displayed at the foot of the page.Whent i launch this script, the magento application is launched like index.php wit the customer id session displayed at the botton of the home page. I just  want to launch an external script retreiving the custommer id session without to launch Magento

Do you have an idea how to do it ?.

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Comment: Also, as I noted in my last comment on my posted answer, you will either have to write your own entry point (not recommended) or add a custom controller/action to Magento with an empty layout, outputting only the session ID. Magento is not exactly intended for having one off scripts pulling this sort of info without doing a bit of work.

Comment: I.e. There is no simple answer of just "do this" and you can bootstrap the HTTP parts of the app to get the session without triggering a rendering.